# JQuery function stops working after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a carousel with infinite loop.

As I'm taking my first steps, it's almost certain that this is far from the best way of doing it.

Anyway, I thought the code was supposed to be correct. In fact, in a first glance it seems to be working fine but right after the first click the function suddenly stops working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function moveToSelected(element) {
    var cards = $('#carousel > div');
    var clickIndex = cards.index(element);
    var mainIndex = cards.index($('.main'));
    
//     6 principal e o cara clica no next
    if (clickIndex == 0 && mainIndex == 5){
      cards.eq(4).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(5).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(0).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(1).removeClass().addClass('next');
//     1 principal e o cara clica no previous
    } else if (clickIndex == 5 && mainIndex == 0){
      cards.eq(1).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(4).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(5).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(0).removeClass().addClass('next');
//     6 principal e o cara clica previous
    } else if (clickIndex == 4 && mainIndex == 5){
      cards.eq(0).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(3).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(4).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(5).removeClass().addClass('next');
//     caso normal next     
    } else if (clickIndex > mainIndex){
      cards.eq(mainIndex-1).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(mainIndex).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(clickIndex).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(clickIndex + 1).removeClass().addClass('next');
//     caso normal previous
    } else if (clickIndex < mainIndex){
      cards.eq(mainIndex + 1).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(clickIndex + 1).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(clickIndex).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(mainIndex).removeClass().addClass('next');
    };
    
  };
  
  $('.previous').click(function() {
    moveToSelected($('.previous'));
  });

  $('.next').click(function() {
      moveToSelected($('.next'));
   });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;  
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#carousel {
  background: red;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  width: 70vw;
}

#carousel > div {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Lato;
  left:50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .7s;
  width: 50%;
}

#carousel > div h3 {
  text-align: center; 
}

.main{
  opacity:1;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.next, .previous{
  display: inline-block;
  opacity:.6;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.next{
  transform: translateX(-20%) scale(.9);
}

.previous{
  transform: translateX(-80%) scale(.9);
  background-color: blue;
}

.hidden{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="main">
    <h3>Módulo 1: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    <h3>Módulo 2: Blablabla</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3>Módulo 3: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3>Módulo 4: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3>Módulo 5: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="previous">
    <h3>6Módulo 6: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code, you should use **event delegation** to solve this, here is the [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$("body").on('click', '#div_id', function(e) {

});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

You can also use **bootstrap** to create Carousel, it simplify your front-end development and you should not worry about jquery

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.portalveneza.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/image1.jpeg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://demo.yootheme.com/themes/joomla/2014/nite/cache/widgetkit/gallery/39/image2-dc3d866a26.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://blogs.gartner.com/john-wheeler/files/2016/05/cool.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Otávio! I need to study more about bootstrap, I've started my journey through front-end a few weeks ago.

Comment: It's makes faster and simple to solve, the other answer `($('#carousel > div').click(handler)):` as I told you it occurs because  you need to use `event delegation`

Answer (score 0):

Your core problem is that you are only giving an event listener to the two initial previous/next items, not all of them. This is easily fixed through code that you already utilize elsewhere (`$('#carousel > div').click(handler)`):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function moveToSelected(element) {
    var cards = $('#carousel > div');
    var clickIndex = cards.index(element);
    var mainIndex = cards.index($('.main'));
    
//     6 principal e o cara clica no next
    if (clickIndex == 0 && mainIndex == 5){
      cards.eq(4).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(5).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(0).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(1).removeClass().addClass('next');
//     1 principal e o cara clica no previous
    } else if (clickIndex == 5 && mainIndex == 0){
      cards.eq(1).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(4).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(5).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(0).removeClass().addClass('next');
//     6 principal e o cara clica previous
    } else if (clickIndex == 4 && mainIndex == 5){
      cards.eq(0).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(3).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(4).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(5).removeClass().addClass('next');
//     caso normal next     
    } else if (clickIndex > mainIndex){
      cards.eq(mainIndex-1).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(mainIndex).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(clickIndex).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(clickIndex + 1).removeClass().addClass('next');
//     caso normal previous
    } else if (clickIndex < mainIndex){
      cards.eq(mainIndex + 1).removeClass().addClass('hidden');
      cards.eq(clickIndex + 1).removeClass().addClass('previous');
      cards.eq(clickIndex).removeClass().addClass('main');
      cards.eq(mainIndex).removeClass().addClass('next');
    };
    
  };
  $('#carousel > div').click(function() {
    if (this.classList.contains("previous") || this.classList.contains("next")) {
      moveToSelected(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;  
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#carousel {
  background: red;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  width: 70vw;
}

#carousel > div {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Lato;
  left:50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .7s;
  width: 50%;
}

#carousel > div h3 {
  text-align: center; 
}

.main{
  opacity:1;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.next, .previous{
  display: inline-block;
  opacity:.6;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.next{
  transform: translateX(-20%) scale(.9);
}

.previous{
  transform: translateX(-80%) scale(.9);
  background-color: blue;
}

.hidden{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="main">
    <h3>Módulo 1: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    <h3>Módulo 2: Blablabla</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3>Módulo 3: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3>Módulo 4: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3>Módulo 5: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="previous">
    <h3>6Módulo 6: Análise Financeira</h3>
    <div class="detail">
      <ul>
        <li> 
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
          Quais são os principais demonstrativos financeiros?
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There seems to be something funky about card display logic (or I'm misunderstanding what it's supposed to do), do tell if you need help with that and how it's supposed to function if so

Comment: Thanks a lot YellowAfterLife. It worked like a charm! It's exactly what I was looking for :)